# How can I use a function in a separate js file in my node.js-Backend as well as in my frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend

In my Web App, I have some mathematical function in some js file. In order to be able to require it in my Node.js-Back-end I have to export said function in said file using module.exports.

```js
    //Needed for Usage in the Back-end
    module.exports = {
        calculate: calculate
    };
```

When I now want to use this file in the Front-end it still contains the above snippet, which is not fatal but somewhat inconvenient.

Is there any better way to use a js file in the front and in the back without duplicating code?

Regards,
Claas M.

Comment: You could look into something like http://browserify.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create node module and <script> in one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322070/create-node-module-and-script-in-one-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the existence of `module.exports` like so

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  module.exports = {
    calculate: calculate
  };
} else {
  window.calculate = calculate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check whether you are in Node.js and if not just use the function differently

```
if(typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.argv[0] === "node") {
    // this is node
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this at the end of your script file:

```
var Ducky = {
    quak: function quak() {
        return "Quack!";
    }
};

if (exports !== undefined && exports !== null) {
    exports.Ducky = Ducky;
} else if (module !== undefined && module !== null &&
        module.exports !== undefined && module.exports !== null) {
    module.exports.Ducky = Ducky;
} else if (window !== undefined && window !== null) {
    window.Ducky = Ducky;
}
```

**Edit:**
You might want to pack this stuff inside a `(function(){})()` expression, so Ducky will not be a global variable.

Comment: You can even use this for non-web / non-node.js applications. Just add another `else if` for your shell (or the code will be ignored)

Answer (score 1):

You can use external which will replace the Node's `require` on the Browser side.

My preference in that case would be [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

With some code modifications you can also try [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any `require` in your server-side module, but only `module.exports`, then you can leave your server-side code as is and put a small snippet into your client side page before you loading any such module:

**Client JavaScript**

```
window.module = {
  set exports (obj) {
    for(p in obj) {
      obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && (window[p] = obj[p]);
    }
  }
};
```

This snippet will put any exported function defined in your server side code and exported with `module.exports` to `window`. This way you don't need to modify all your shared code by adding redundant stuff, but add only once a small piece of code only to your client.

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/2fWlNN5w7R4Mcdv9VJ5T?p=preview

Supported by all modern browsers starting from IE9:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set